# Fetching data from Cassandra is too slow

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

We have a cluster of 3 cassandra nodes. All nodes are working fine, but fetching results is EXTREMELY slow. I run a `SELECT`-query in cql-shell to fetch ~100k of rows and before starting to show me first results it may take up to 30 seconds to warm-up.

Why it may happen? Is there any way to speed it up?

Here is a trace log:

```
activity                                                                                                                                              | timestamp    | source         | source_elapsed
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+----------------
                                                                                                                                   execute_cql3_query | 17:41:34,923 | *.*.*.211 |              0
Parsing SELECT * FROM ga_page_visits WHERE site_global_key='GLOBAL_KEY' AND reported_at < '2014-05-17' AND reported_at > '2014-05-01' LIMIT 100000; | 17:41:34,923 | *.*.*.211 |             87
                                                                                                                                  Preparing statement | 17:41:34,923 | *.*.*.211 |            290
                                                                                                                   Sending message to /*.*.*.213 | 17:41:34,924 | *.*.*.211 |           1579
                                                                                                                   Sending message to /*.*.*.212 | 17:41:34,924 | *.*.*.211 |           1617
                                                                                                            Executing single-partition query on users | 17:41:34,924 | *.*.*.211 |           1666
                                                                                                                Message received from /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.213 |             48
                                                                                                                Message received from /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.212 |             40
                                                                                                                         Acquiring sstable references | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           1704
                                                                                                                          Merging memtable tombstones | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           1767
                                                                                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 2 | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           1886
                                                                                                          Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           1908
                                                                            Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           2337
                                                                                                           Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           2366
                                                                                                                   Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 17:41:34,925 | *.*.*.211 |           2410
                                                                                                            Executing single-partition query on users | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.213 |            702
                                                                                                            Executing single-partition query on users | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.212 |            813
                                                                                                                         Acquiring sstable references | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.213 |            747
                                                                                                                         Acquiring sstable references | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.212 |            848
                                                                                                                          Merging memtable tombstones | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.213 |            838
                                                                                                                          Merging memtable tombstones | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.212 |            922
                                                                                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 5 | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.213 |           1006
                                                                                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 1 | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.212 |           1044
                                                                                                          Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.213 |           1034
                                                                                                          Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 17:41:34,926 | *.*.*.212 |           1066
                                                                            Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.213 |           1635
                                                                            Skipped 0/1 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.212 |           1543
                                                                                                           Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.213 |           1676
                                                                                                           Merging data from memtables and 1 sstables | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.212 |           1571
                                                                                                                   Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.213 |           1760
                                                                                                                   Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.212 |           1634
                                                                                                                Enqueuing response to /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.213 |           2014
                                                                                                                Enqueuing response to /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.212 |           1846
                                                                                                                   Sending message to /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.213 |           2173
                                                                                                                   Sending message to /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,927 | *.*.*.212 |           1960
                                                                                                                Message received from /*.*.*.213 | 17:41:34,928 | *.*.*.211 |           4759
                                                                                                                Message received from /*.*.*.212 | 17:41:34,928 | *.*.*.211 |           4775
                                                                                                             Processing response from /*.*.*.213 | 17:41:34,928 | *.*.*.211 |           5439
                                                                                                             Processing response from /*.*.*.212 | 17:41:34,928 | *.*.*.211 |           5668
                                                                                                                     Sending message to /*.*.*.40 | 17:41:34,929 | *.*.*.211 |           5954
                                                                                                   Executing single-partition query on ga_page_visits | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           6792
                                                                                                                         Acquiring sstable references | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           6868
                                                                                                                          Merging memtable tombstones | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           6936
                                                                                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 2 | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           7075
                                                                                                    Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           7102
                                                                                                                          Key cache hit for sstable 1 | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           7211
                                                                                                    Seeking to partition indexed section in data file | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           7232
                                                                            Skipped 1/3 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           7290
                                                                                                           Merging data from memtables and 2 sstables | 17:41:34,930 | *.*.*.211 |           7311
                                                                                                                Message received from /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,964 |   *.*.*.40 |             45
                                                                                                            Executing single-partition query on users | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |            658
                                                                                                                         Acquiring sstable references | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |            695
                                                                                                                          Merging memtable tombstones | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |            762
                                                                                                                         Key cache hit for sstable 14 | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |            852
                                                                                                          Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |            876
                                                                                                                         Key cache hit for sstable 16 | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |           1275
                                                                                                          Seeking to partition beginning in data file | 17:41:34,965 |   *.*.*.40 |           1293
                                                                            Skipped 0/2 non-slice-intersecting sstables, included 0 due to tombstones | 17:41:34,966 |   *.*.*.40 |           1504
                                                                                                           Merging data from memtables and 2 sstables | 17:41:34,966 |   *.*.*.40 |           1526
                                                                                                                   Read 1 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 17:41:34,966 |   *.*.*.40 |           1592
                                                                                                                Enqueuing response to /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,966 |   *.*.*.40 |           1755
                                                                                                                   Sending message to /*.*.*.211 | 17:41:34,966 |   *.*.*.40 |           1834
                                                                                                                  Message received from /*.*.*.40 | 17:41:34,980 | *.*.*.211 |          57679
                                                                                                               Processing response from /*.*.*.40 | 17:41:34,981 | *.*.*.211 |          57785
                                                                                                               Read 99880 live and 0 tombstoned cells | 17:41:36,315 | *.*.*.211 |        1392676
                                                                                                                                     Request complete | 17:41:37,541 | *.*.*.211 |        2618390
```

The table schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE ga_page_visits (
  site_global_key ascii,
  reported_at timestamp,
  timeuuid ascii,
  bounces int,
  campaign text,
  channel ascii,
  conversions int,
  device ascii,
  keyword text,
  medium text,
  new_visits int,
  page_id int,
  page_views int,
  referral_path text,
  site_search_engine_id int,
  social_network text,
  source text,
  value decimal,
  visits int,
  PRIMARY KEY (site_global_key, reported_at, timeuuid)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

Comment: Can you post the schema of `ga_page_visits`?

Comment: Sure, just added schema to original post

Comment: How long does it take for 1K, 10K, and 50K rows respectively?

Comment: Also, (you may want to put this in a gist) your machine specs, your cassandra.yaml, and your cassandra-env.  If you enable GC messages in your logs, that would be fantastic too.

Comment: Time log:
for 1k rows it takes 0.87s before data starts to come;
for 10k rows - 4.24s;
for 50k rows - 18.51s

Comment: First, doing a select like this is not the most efficient way getting data from a Cassandra table. Is this a normal access pattern? I would expect a query like this to take a long time because it's just not how Cassandra works. The other question I have is what kind of systems are these? The fact that it takes so long just to fetch that data looks like some really under powered systems. Especially disk.

Comment: @JonathanHaddad - Here is gist with cassandra config: https://gist.github.com/ilkon/9d324d2ac81ca590f320 . The server specs are: CPU: i7-4770 @ 3.40GHz (8 cores). Memory total: 32 Gb.

Comment: @PatrickMcFadin - Yes, this is a quite common request, fetching data for given site_global_key and given date range (reported_at is a timestamp field). Do you think that column family scheme is inefficient, or request itself?

The server specs are: CPU: i7-4770 @ 3.40GHz (8 cores). Memory total: 32 Gb. Disk is 10% full, quite modern, I guess it's SATA3.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand how this table is being used, for a given site_global_key, you're pushing in a bunch of timestamped data, making this a time series table, correct?  What's the result for "select count(*) from ga_page_visits where site_global_key = 'GLOBAL_KEY' limit 10000000"

Comment: @JonathanHaddad - Yes, that's correct, it's a time series table. "select count(*)" takes up to 3-4 seconds to calculate, and returns 179308 for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you've got an issue with your data model.  It looks like you're pushing in an absolute ton of data into a single partition.  That will become a problem as your data set gets bigger.  I recommend this type of structure instead:

```
CREATE TABLE ga_page_visits (
  site_global_key ascii,
  day timestamp,
  timeuuid ascii,
  bounces int,
  campaign text,
  channel ascii,
  conversions int,
  device ascii,
  keyword text,
  medium text,
  new_visits int,
  page_id int,
  page_views int,
  referral_path text,
  site_search_engine_id int,
  social_network text,
  source text,
  value decimal,
  visits int,
  PRIMARY KEY ((site_global_key, day), timeuuid)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

You already have a timeuuid, that has a time embedded in it, so you don't need a reported_at timestamp.

You are going to have a ridiculous number of rows in this partition.  You should use a composite primary key of site_global_key & the date (do not add the time, let it be 00:00:00.)

This way, each day will live on a separate partition and is more easily queried.  Do 1 query for each day.  This will perform much better.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like a most reasonable solution for this problem. Unfortunately I cannot use it - if 'day' will be a part of composite partition key, I cannot use date ranges for fetching results. Instead I'll have to query results for each day from range separately and merge result sets later. It seems to be that Cassandra is not most suitable storage for our needs.

Comment: Performing 1 query per day will be significantly faster, and joining the results of 12 queries should simply be creating a new list from 12 smaller lists?  Why is there a hard requirement that everything be fetched with 1 query?

Comment: It's worth it, as an exercise, to do the 12 queries & merge them into a single list, before you switch databases.  I think you'll be surprised just how well this works.

Comment: Merging fetched result sets is not an option because it's not only for date range of 12 days. There may be selection for one quarter (92 days) or one year. Also, it's hard to do parallel queries in our application, so all these queries must be called consequently. 365 sequential calls - it's not the best solution for processing user request in real time.

Comment: Generally if you're going to need more than just daily views, it's a good use case to do weekly / monthly rollups.  If you're using the java driver, it comes with async support as well.  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/1.0/java-driver/asynchronous_t.html.  Just as an FYI, if you want to process tens of millions of rows client side, fetching the data synchronously is going to be a mess no matter what DB you use.

Answer (score 1):

As I'm looking at your model requirements, this is really looking like a data warehouse type design. Jon nailed it with the rollups. If you need low latency, high frequency creating those tighter views of your data is done often in production with high scaling requirements. I don't want to spray out links but there are examples of this if you google.